# Android Sqlite : assign one column's values to another using ContentValues

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I want to assign one column's values to another.

here is a query for it.

```
UPDATE contacts SET contactName=phone;
```

Here contactName and phone are two different columns.i am assigning phone column's values to contactName column.I can do this by using

```
db.execSQL(statement);
```

but if i want it to update it using

```
db.update(tableName, cValues, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

what should i put in Content values.If i put phone as a value then it will consider like

```
UPDATE contacts SET contactName="phone";
```

Is it possible using content values?
Help me to solve this issue.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `ContentValues` for that. You can only update/insert literal values with `ContentValues`, not column name references.

Just use `execSQL()` with the raw SQL you have. (Don't use `rawQuery()` - it alone won't execute your SQL.)

Comment: sorry i have used execSQL but i want to do it using content values

Comment: That's not possible. What is the problem with the raw SQL approach?

Comment: actually i have implemented it using execSQL.but just i wanted to know about it.I googled it but couldn't find any solution.thats why i asked it here.bdw Thanks.